# Netmiko/Paramiko Configure proxy tunnel

Tags: ssh, paramiko

`Host machine ---- Jumpserver ( account password and then RSA Token password ) ---- SSH to cisco devices.`

How do I create `SSH` sessions to end devices after `SSH` connection to jump host has been established using the below code.
Also, if there is a better way to handle authentication with jumpserver that asks for auth password and `RSA` token as [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H6Cn.jpg).

```py
    import paramiko
    from paramiko import SSHException
    import logging
        
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    paramiko.common.logging.basicConfig(level=paramiko.common.DEBUG)
    
    ssh.connect(hostname="jump_server_ip", port=22)
    ssh.get_transport().auth_interactive_dumb(("username", "password"))
```

after pushing this command `ssh.get_transport().auth_interactive_dumb(username="username")`
I get this [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H6Cn.jpg).

Thank You

Comment: For the purposes of testing, i was able to leverage keyboard-interactive for both 

Password:                 --- > This is the password for the username I give.
Enter PASSCODE:      --- > This is the RSA token that I need to supply

This is just one time, so it can be keyboard-interactive, doesn't matter
but once SSH to jumphost is established, there needs to be multiple SSH connections to hundreds of end hosts tunnel through this jumphost.

I am not sure how do I go about achieving that.

Comment: So basically, 
after pushing this command
`ssh.get_transport().auth_interactive_dumb(username="username")`
I get this
[Link](https://imgur.com/CykeOEA)
I need help with the next step of action....
How do i proceed from here to establish connections to end hosts.

Comment: Thank you and sorry you had dig this out of me. Excuse the beginner in me trying to solve what is seemingly complicated for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239785/discussion-between-gurpreet-kochar-and-martin-prikryl).